# Need to add events to calendar

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, events, calendar

I currently have code that creates a monthly calendar:

```
 var i = 1;

 do{

     var writeDays = new Date(year, month, i).getDay();
     //if it's Sunday, start a new row
     if(writeDays == 0)
     {
         html += '<tr>';
     }
     //if it's not Sunday but the first day of the month, write the last days from the previous month
     else if(i == 1)
     {
         html += '<tr>';
         var count = lastDayofPreviousMonth - firstDayofMonth + 1;
         for(var j = 0; j < firstDayofMonth; j++)
         {
             html += '<td class = "not-current">' + count + '</td>';
             count++;

         }
     }

     html += '<td class = "hover">' + i  + '</td>';


     //if it's Saturday, ends the row
     if(writeDays == 6)
     {
     html += '</tr>';
     }
     //if it isn't Saturday, but last day of the current month, write the next few days from the next month
     else if(i == lastDayofMonth)
     {
     var count = 1;
     for(writeDays; writeDays < 6; writeDays++)
     {
     html += '<td class = "not-current">' + count + '</td>';
     count++;
     }
     }
     i++;
 }
 while(i <= lastDayofMonth);
```

I want to be able click on a day (cell) in the array and add an event to the day. I'm not too sure how to implement this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can add an eventListener to the table element.
for example.I have a table dom like this,which I believe is similiar to your dom structure:

```
<table id='tb'>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

and I want every td element can respone to a click event,so I can do this:

```
var table=document.getElementById('tb');
table.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  console.log(e);
});
```

in parameter e,you can get a lot information.just try it.